# Is there a way of clicking an specific point/element in a canvas (with javascript, jquery or selenium)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium, canvas

How can I apply a click at a specific position in a canvas? (using coordinates seems the most logical to me, but can't find any way to do it, any other idea is welcomed). Note that I do not have access to the code that creates the canvas.

EDIT: Some clarification, the canvas has multiple elements being drawn that i can't select with jquery but need to click them. I could find their coordinates manually and do some calculations, but every time i try to pass a click or mouse event into that position is not being taken as a real mouse click (the button that should be clicked, is not).

Answer (score 1):

How about trying

```
canvas.on('click', function(e) {

    // calculate x y coordinates on canvas
    var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left,
    y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;

    // implement collision detection via the coordinates the element you want to click (assuming you know where it is)
    if (y > <elementY> && y < <elementY> + <elementHeight>
        && x > <elementX> && x < <elementX> + <elementWidth>) {
        alert('found it');
    }
});
```

I have no time testing that snippet. If you know the x and y coordinates of your elements within your canvas, that code might just do the trick.

What I tried to do with that snippet is to simulate a bounding box via `elmentY` and `elementY + elementHeight` as well as `elementX` and `elementX + elementWidth`. If you know all those values, you can simply check whether the `x` and `y` values of your click event fall in that said box.

**Edit**

If you want to trigger a click event at a certain position, define the clickEvent beforehand and set the pageX and pageY attributes.

```
var e = new jQuery.Event("click");
e.pageX = 10;
e.pageY = 10;
$(<canvas>).trigger(e);
```

You might have to include the offset of your canvas in the calculations as well.

Comment: But after getting the coordinates, what function can i use after that to click at that point?

Comment: so you want to trigger a click at certain coordinates?

Comment: I passed the click event using relative coordinates to the canvas and absolute to the entire page, but still nothing

Comment: if you register the click even to the canvas, you should be able to log something in there. you could debug whether to coordinates you passed were the same the canvas received when you clicked on it.